# Persistence errors when switching from self-hosted workflow to a workflow service in Workflow Foundation 4

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, workflow-foundation-4

I am developing an application that is using a state machine constructed in Windows Workflow Foundation 4 in order to control the workflow of several application tiers. The workflow executes admirably, for the most part, however unexpected problems appeared when sqlWorkflowInstanceStore was added.

More specifically, when running as a workflow service some of the necessary data (ActiveBookmarks, ExecutionStatus, IsInitialized, IsSuspended and a few other fields) does not get saved into the database when a workflow is persisted.

I have spent several days debugging this only to find that when the exact same workflow is run with the exact same settings, but as a self-hosted activity, instead of a workflow service everything performs without a hitch. This leads me to believe that the problem is somewhere in the server/host configuration.

I am going to try hosting under different configs as well as hosting an activity in IIS as per these guides:

[Hosting a self-hosted WF in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192466/hosting-a-self-hosted-wf-in-iis)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729688.aspx

However, if someone can point me to a more specific reason for this error, I would be very grateful as this is currently the single biggest issue that needs to be tackled before we can release.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some information as to what errors are occurring. So far you are only telling us what is not happening and that is very little to go on. Try adding a trace listener and checking what errors popup in the trace file.

Comment: I ran the trace listener and the message I got was as follows:
"The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance '42b5db91-3529-4fd6-8db8-2bc42312bc76' has not yet been persisted to the instance store."

An instance with the key in question is, however, present in the database. It has several fields missing, as I mentioned before. There are no other exceptions or errors in the log.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with the original persistence. I am sure there is an exception being thrown there and would expect it to be because you are using a type in your workflow that isn't marked as Serializable.

Comment: Anyone get anywhere with this? I am having some strange problems with persistence and state machines in WF too. It's not persisting at all and I can't see why.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [How to troubleshoot Windows Server AppFabric and Workflows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/04/how-to-troubleshoot-windows-server-appfabric-and-workflows.aspx)